# Easy way to show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos x}{1+\frac{i}2-(1+i)\sin x} dx =0$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

I am looking for easy way to show that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos \varphi}{1+\frac{i}2-(1+i)\sin \varphi} d \varphi =0$.

I can evaluate this integral myself via the following approach:

1. Substitution: $z=e^{i \varphi}$, $\sin \varphi = \frac{1}{2i}(z - \frac1z)$, $\cos \varphi = \frac{1}{2}(z + \frac1z)$, $d \varphi = -i \frac{dz}{z}$.
2. Residule calculus. In my case I have to perform substation, determine poles within unit circle and compute the residue.

It took me a lot of time and efforts to get final $0$. But $0$ means there is some kind of symmetry here. I guess it can be exploited to get final result without messy calculations. Can you help me to find smart approach?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Symmetry, indeed... For every $t$ in $(0,\pi)$, $$\cos(\pi-t)=-\cos t\qquad\sin(\pi-t)=\sin t$$ hence, for every non real complex number $w$, the change of variable $s=\pi-t$ yields $$\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos t}{w-\sin t}dt=\int_\pi^0\frac{-\cos s}{w-\sin s}(-ds)=-\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos s}{w-\sin s}ds$$ which proves that $$\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos t}{w-\sin t}dt=0$$ Likewise for the integral on $(\pi,2\pi)$.

Comment: @Did: Please promote your comment to the answer I will accept it. Also please elaborate why $w$ should be complex and what is wrong with real $w$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $w$ is real, then the denominator $w-\sin t$ might be zero at some point $t$ in $[0,2\pi]$.